# SSIS Inserting incrementing ID with starting range into multiple tables at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

Is there are one or some reliable variants to solve easy task? 
I've got a number of XML files which will be converting into 6 SQL tables (via SSIS).
Before the end of this process i need to add a new (in fact - common for all tables) column (or field) into each of them.

This column represents ID with assigning range and +1 incrementing step. Like (350000, 1)
Yes, i know how to solve it on SSMS SQL stage. But i need a solution at SSIS's pre-SQL converting lvl. 
I'm sure there should be well-known pattern-solutions to deal with it.

Comment: I believe the common way is to use a Script task with a counter-like variable that fills your new column on the `ProcessInputRow` method, but this makes your DTS synchronous (need to process row by row, although it's still fast), so it's not a good option if you are looking for performance.

Comment: Is this model like [link](https://imgur.com/XmYZMAB). I saw it. But for me that was an example for one-table script. At first time i can't transform it for multiple tables.
Could it be realized in a model like [link](https://imgur.com/yh6i73U) (one script produce one common id in one cycle)? How fast it doesn't much matter.
Or there is could be another ssis' element configuration?

Comment: You can generate a workflow like the 2nd image but your input buffer must be unified. You will have to union all your different inputs (if you have more than 1) into the script transform, add your new ID column, then conditionally split the outputs (either inside the script component via multiple Output buffers or outside the script with conditional splits over a column).

Comment: I use script tasks/components for processing XML and JSON especially when you are getting the data from a web service that allows you receive information back straight into an object. I guess my point is that you can get the identity column back when making an insert in order to apply into other tables as a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at this. Just to be clear, I don't have a lot of information in your question to go on.

Most XML files that I have dealt with have a common element (let's call it a customer) with one to many attributes (this can be invoices, addresses, email, contacts, etc).

So your table structure will be somewhat star shaped around the customer.

So your XML will have a core customer information on a 1 to 1 basis that can be loaded into a single main table, and will have array information of invoices and an array of addresses etc. Those arrays would be their own tables referencing the customer as a key.

**I think you are asking how to create that key.**

Load the customer data first and return the identity column to be used as a foreign key when loading  the other tables.

I find it easiest to do so in script component. I'm only going to explain how to get the key back. I personally would handle the whole process in C# (deserializing and all).

Add this to Using Block:

```
Using System.Data.OleDB;
```

Add this into your main or row processing depending on where the script task / component is:

```
string SQL = @"INSERT INTO Customer(CustName,field1, field2,...)
               values(?,?,?,...); Select cast(scope_identity() as int);";

OleDBCommanad cmd = new OleDBCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",[CustName]);
...
cmd.Connection.Open();
int CustomerKey = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //ExecuteScalar returns the value in first row / first column which in our case is scope_identity
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Now you can use CustomerKey for all of the other tables.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement it.